# Only one flag option on some posts

Tags: bug, flags, flag-dialog

I attempted to flag [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662439/2057919) as not an answer, but the flag dialog only has one option: "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)."  I have run into that a couple of other times.  Why is that?

It's not because I have a high number of disputed or declined flags; I'm running at about a 97% helpful rate, with no disputes or declines in the last couple hundred or so.

Comment: Looks like it was deleted between the time you visited the page and the time you clicked "flag".  That flag option is shown when an answer is deleted.

Comment: Well, that would explain it. You're right; it's gone now.

Comment: P.S. If you make that an answer, I will accept it. I think this is a useful enough question that I don't want to delete it; I've looked for this answer myself a couple of times in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disappearing options for flagging happens because the answer was deleted between the time you visited the page and the time you clicked "flag".

That sole flag option is shown when an answer is deleted.